# Unrecognised HLINT pragma in Haskell

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, haskell-stack, hlint

I'm trying to disable some warnings that HLint is giving me. [According to docs](https://www.stackage.org/nightly-2021-01-13/package/hlint-3.2.6) I should be able to add a pragma to the top of my file.  So I tried the following:

```hs
{-# HLINT ignore #-}
module Main where
```

Which however gives me an error when running `stack build`:

```
/Users/nene/somedir/src/Main.hs:1:1: warning: [-Wunrecognised-pragmas]
    Unrecognised pragma
  |
1 | {-# HLINT ignore #-}
  | ^^^
```

Seems like the pragma actually works in my editor (VSCode with "Haskell" extension), but is not recognized when running `stack`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a pragma without any warnings, you can use the `ANN` pragma like this:

```hs
{-# ANN module "HLint: ignore" #-}
```

However I would recommend using a regular comment instead of a pragma:

```hs
{- HLINT ignore -}
```

I prefer regular comments because they don't have weird rules like pragmas do. In fact [the documentation](https://github.com/ndmitchell/hlint/blob/5346cbe29fe585bc6aef80fddc3800743c48c8db/README.md#ignoring-hints) notes:

> For `ANN` pragmas it is important to put them after any import statements. If you have the `OverloadedStrings` extension enabled you will need to give an explicit type to the annotation, e.g. `{-# ANN myFunction ("HLint: ignore" :: String) #-}`. The `ANN` pragmas can also increase compile times or cause more recompilation than otherwise required, since they are evaluated by `TemplateHaskell`.
>
> For `{-# HLINT #-}` pragmas GHC may give a warning about an unrecognised pragma, which can be suppressed with `-Wno-unrecognised-pragmas`.

Comment: Aha... "After any imports". That's the thing I didn't notice when initially attempting to use an ANN pragma. I tried to put it at the beginning of a file, which resulted in really strange parse errors.

Comment: But you're right. I'll gladly use comments instead. Being a novice at Haskell, I really don't want burden myself with learning pragmas right now.

Comment: @ReneSaarsoo: I think the only pragma you really need to be aware of as a beginner is `LANGUAGE`, which explicitly enables language features. You may also see `OPTIONS_GHC` sometimes for specifying extra compiler options. You can ignore others until you need them; they control more advanced optimisations, warnings, and type system features. Also, pragma names are case-insensitive, so you can write e.g. `{-# Language BlockArguments #-}` if you prefer.